# ¿Tiene algún tipo de virus o algo raro para robar archivos esta fuente?

Tags: windows

Esta fuente está programada para poner contraseña a las carpetas de windows. Y antes de guardar algún tipo de carpeta me gustaría saber si es seguro. La fuente es la siguiente:

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Folder Private 
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren Private "HTG Locker" 
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to unlock folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== CONTRASEÑA goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker" 
ren "HTG Locker" Private 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDLOCKER 
md Private 
echo Private created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad es un fichero por lotes de windows, imagino que con extension `.bat` o `.cmd` o similar. Lo que hace ese código es ocultar y marcar una carpeta como de sistema para que no puedas borrarla ni verla y también hacer el proceso inverso si le pasas una contraseña.

Esto no es nada peligroso ni es nada que tu no puedas revertir. La primera instrucción `cls` lo que hace el limpiar la salida en caso que haya algo escrito en ella así que no es un lenguaje ni nada parecido.

Aqui tienes una descripción paso a paso del algoritmo

```
limpiar la pantalla 
desactiva mostrar los comandos que se están ejecutando 
pon el título de la ventana a "Folder Private" 
si existe la carpeta "HTG Locker" ve a la etiqueta :UNLOCK 
si no existe la carpeta "Private" ve a la etiqueta :MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
pregunta "Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)"
establece la variable "cho" con lo que el usario escriba 
si escribió "Y" o "y" ve a la etiqueta :LOCK 
si escribió "N" o "n" ve a la etiqueta :END 
si no es ninguna de las anteriores ve a la etiqueta :CONFIRM
:LOCK 
renombre la carpeta "Private" a "HTG Locker" 
ponle los atributos oculto y sistema a la carpeta "HTG Locker" 
escribe "Folder locked" y termina 
:UNLOCK 
Escribe "Enter password to unlock folder"
establece la variable "pass" con lo que el usario escriba  
si "pass" no es igual a CONTRASEÑA ve a la etiqueta :FAIL 
quita los atributos oculto y sistema a la carpeta "HTG Locker" 
renombra la carpeta "HTG Locker" a "Private"
escribe "Folder Unlocked successfully" y termina
:FAIL 
escribe "Invalid password" y termina
:MDLOCKER 
crea una carpeta llamada "Private" 
escribe "Private created successfully" y termina
```

Debes tener cuidado porque el windows puede que no interprete bien la constraseña `"CONTRASEÑA"` por la `"Ñ"` y no te deje desbloquear la carpeta en cuyo caso sólo ejecuta

```
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker"
```

y toda la supuesta "protección" se le desactiva ;).

Si quieres saber lo que hacen algunos de esos comandos sólo abre la consola en una pc que tenga windows y ejecuta `help <comando>` o sólo `help` para listar todos los comandos.

Answer (score 0):

No deberías tener ningún problema en usarlo por temas de seguridad, simplemente asegúrate de asignarle una contraseña al editar el archivo y estará listo para funcionar.

Comment: Lo de la contraseña se como va, pero me refiero temas de robar archivos, y cosas por el estilo tipo robar datos y demás...